# How to add 3 currency symbol in textview android

Tags: java, android, html, unicode, unicode-string

I can add dollar symbol. But how to add 3 currency symbol and place it in textview? Is there any unicode/UTF to use it?

```
<string name="dollar">$</string> //this is for dollar symbol.
```

and I used in textview by refering this string.

But for 3 currency symbol [image: 3 currency symbol] ?

Comment: I've never seen this symbol before.  Can you give us the Unicode sequence for it?  Also, you didn't post text, so we can't easily Google search for it either.

Comment: i don't think it is a currency symbol. you can add this image to textview by drawableLeft attribute.

Comment: which countries are using the 3 currency symbol?

Comment: Without using image, it's not possible?

Comment: Indonesia. But client mentioned as 3 currency symbol as requirement. I am not sure about currency symbol or not. @CaoMinhVu

Comment: @Walter its image check here symbol of indonesia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_rupiah

Comment: These are the currency symbols supported by unicode: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Sc

Comment: @Walter The image link in your question is broken. Please do not host images on external services. StackOverflow has its own image hosting service